# The specified service is marked for deletion on a delphi application

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2, uninstallation

I write a Delphi application (basically a GUI for managing a service, it has the following features: allow the user to set some parameters that are used by the service and start/stop/unintsall/install new version).
So among all the features there is one that "doesn't behave properly": at a certain point the app tries to uninstall and install a new version of the a service.

With `ShellExecute` I run the following commands:

```
C:\myPath\myService.exe /Uninstall
C:\myPath\myService.exe /Install  // this is tipically done to install a newer version of it
```

In case the service is already running it is uninstalled succesfully (i get "succesfully uninstalled" message), but if I open services.msc I see that myService is still in the list of services but with Start and Stop disabled from its popupmenu (while I would like it is not listed at all).

At this moment if I try to install the service I get the following error:
"The specified service is marked for deletion"

Note that if i run the uninstall and install commands from  the command prompt the uninstalling is fine and the service is not in services.msc list. Note: in this case I mean not using Delphi (or compiled exe) at all.

I tried with many tricks, including putting a `Sleep(10000)` after uninstallation but it didn't work i also tried by keeping services.msc closed (as i read it could be  a problem to leave it opened).

I found a succesful trick using the following steps:

1) I put a breakpoint just after calling Uninstall from Delphi

2) I go to services.msc : the service is still in the list, even after "Refresh" it is stil in the list

3) I break (from the IDE: CTRL+F2) the exceution of the application

4) I go again in services.msc I click the "refresh" button : myservice is removed from the list as it should be

**So i suspect Delphi XE2 (either debugging in the IDE or running the exe) is somehow "locking the service" not allowing it to be totally uninstalled.**

NOTE: The service is built using another delphi project!

Could you help me understanding why service uninstallation made by `ShellExecute` does give this error?

Thanks a lot.

**IMPORTANT:**
i forgot to mention that i use IDE and cmd.exe as admin.

Comment: stop the service BEFORE you uninstall it (net stop "yourservicename")

Comment: yes i stop it even if not using net stop, but using WinSvc way

Comment: also with NEt STop i got the same....

Comment: Why are you using shell execute when you could call the service manager's API directly? Using SvCom would give a service exe the ability to be (un)installed by using service.exe /uninstall and it would call the appropriate API to do so. Mind you, never tried to (un)install one of our services running from the IDE though.

Comment: Are you waiting for it to completely stop before uninstalling?

Comment: A service is marked for deletion if there are still other processes with current handles to that service. Carefully go through your code and close all handles you got from the service manager.I know I read about this once in the msdn documentation but I am on my phone right now. I'll try to get back and make a proper answer later.

Comment: @SpaghettiCook your idea seems hitting the nail, please write some more if you can.

Comment: @user193655, I wrote more. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had a similar experience. In my code it turned out I used a variable to keep an open connection to the service control manager. Nowadays, I declare all handles as local variables and services install and uninstall on the fly.

You can uninstall a service by calling [DeleteService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In the remarks section it reads:

> The DeleteService function marks a service for deletion from the service control manager database. The database entry is not removed until all open handles to the service have been closed by calls to the CloseServiceHandle function, and the service is not running. A running service is stopped by a call to the ControlService function with the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP control code. If the service cannot be stopped, the database entry is removed when the system is restarted.

Thus, it must be stopped and you should close all handles. The code below should do the trick:

```
function  UninstallService(aServiceName: String; aTimeOut: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
    ComputerName: array[0..MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1] of Char;
    ComputerNameLength, StartTickCount: Cardinal;
    SCM: SC_HANDLE;
    ServiceHandle: SC_HANDLE;
    ServiceStatus: TServiceStatus;

begin
    Result:= False;

    ComputerNameLength:= MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    if (Windows.GetComputerName(ComputerName, ComputerNameLength)) then
    begin
        SCM:= OpenSCManager(ComputerName, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
        if (SCM <> 0) then
        begin
            try
                ServiceHandle:= OpenService(SCM, PChar(aServiceName), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
                if (ServiceHandle <> 0) then
                begin

                    // make sure service is stopped
                    QueryServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ServiceStatus);
                    if (not (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState in [0, SERVICE_STOPPED])) then
                    begin
                        // Stop service
                        ControlService(ServiceHandle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ServiceStatus);
                    end;

                    // wait for service to be stopped
                    StartTickCount:= GetTickCount;
                    QueryServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ServiceStatus);
                    if (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState <> SERVICE_STOPPED) then
                    begin
                        repeat
                            Sleep(1000);
                            QueryServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ServiceStatus);
                        until (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED) or ((GetTickCount - StartTickCount) > aTimeout);
                    end;

                    Result:= DeleteService(ServiceHandle);
                    CloseServiceHandle(ServiceHandle);
                end;
            finally
                CloseServiceHandle(SCM);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I would chop the code above in a few sub functions (i.e. QueryServiceStatus, StopService and UninstallService), but for testing whether this code works for you I thought it best to write it in one simple solution. On a final note, don't forget the process needs sufficient rights to execute this code successfully.

Comment: Perfect, this worked! using this same function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for the 300 points. I feel so manly now :-) On a more important note, I just noted quite an important bug in the code snippet above. I corrected it, please copy. The timeout comparison in the repeat until block was the wrong way around. You may not notice this if your service stops in a timely fashion. Otherwise you will be in the loop forever, which is a long time.

Comment: THanks for the update, i will check it. you deserved the 300 points, this is how StackOverflow works!

Answer (score 2):

I think your command prompt has elevated rights and is therefor allowed to actually stop the service. Delphi may not be, or at least your project is not, so it is allowed to uninstall the service (which is little more than removing some values from the registry), but it cannot actually stop the service.

The service is then 'marked for deletion', because it is already uninstalled, but still running. If you'd restart your pc, the service wouldn't be started again, and your tool could install the new version.

If my guess it right, then the solution would be to run your program -which is essentially an installer- as Administrator, so it also has the rights to immediately stop and remove the service.

One other thing you might try, is to call `net stop <service>` first to stop the service, but I doubt if that solves the issue.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that i am using IDE and command prompt "as an administrator". I will update the question.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. But I think that your project doesn't inherit these administrator rights, so even though your IDE runs as an administrator, your own program, even when started from the IDE, does not. Not 100% sure about that, though.

Comment: Program started by elevated IDE inherits elevation

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for clearing that up. Really odd then, that ShellExecute behaves differently than running the commands from the prompt.

Comment: i will try with "net stop" too and let you know

Comment: also with Net stop same behavior! Killing IDE makes uninstall succesful as descirbed in the question, that is the problem